# Не работает autoplay в теге audio в Google Chrome. Кто нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Tags: html5, аудио

Не работает в Chrome.
Пробовал иммитровать клик при загрузке странице по кнопке которая воспроизводит аудио(типа autoplay) но тоже в  Chrome безуспешно.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var button = $("#for_audio");
        var audio = new Audio('music/1.wav');
        setTimeout(function(){
            button.trigger('click');
        });
        button.click(function() {
                audio.play();
        });
    });
</script>
```

В Safari и FF всё ок.

Comment: Вы не передает в setTimeout время задержки setTimeout(func, 1000); И почему сразу не запустить play? Зачем имитировать клик?

Comment: Исправил так как вы написали. Но в Chrome выдает ошыбку:
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. https://goo.gl/xX8pDD

Comment: В хроме по умолчанию не работает autoplay

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var button = $("#for_audio");
        var audio = new Audio('https://html5book.ru/examples/media/track.mp3');
        setTimeout(function(){
           audio.play();
        }, 1000);
        button.click(function() {
                audio.play();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Что скажете на счет ошибки у меня в консоли?
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. https://goo.gl/xX8pDD

Comment: @AleksandrMokriak Создайте в песочнице самодостаточный пример.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v9j555np/1/

Comment: @AleksandrMokriak https://jsfiddle.net/v9j555np/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
function  playSound(url){
    var audio= document.createElement('embed');
    audio.src=url;
    audio.style="width:0px;height:0px";
    document.body.appendChild(audio);
}
```

ну а что делать, если звук нужен

при данном способе есть предупреждение в консоли "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type audio/mpeg..."